# Referencing text on a button element?

Tags: expressions, terminology

If a button on a website has text on it, how do you reference that text?

For example, if a button had the text "click here" on it would you say "the button that says 'click here'" or "the button that reads 'click here'"?

Is there a better way of referencing the text on that button besides saying "the button with the text 'click here'"?

Comment: The 'click-here' button?

Comment: All three of your alternatives are fine. I am not seeing a problem. If you are trying to grade them by some criterion other than grammaticality, you will have to be more explicit about what that criterion is. "Better" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Grammatically, these are fine, but from a web development /usability standpoint, you shouldn't really have a button that says "click here".  The button text should describe what will happen when they click it.  Something like "Log In", "Sign Up", "Continue", "Delete", "Process", etc.  Then you would just call it the "Signup Button" or the "Continue Button" or even just "Click Continue Below:"

Comment: See definition for "button text". For the technically correct answer, we should ask on [ux.se].

Comment: Eli, I used "click here" as an example for this question for the sake of simplicity. Thanks for the concern though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would you say "the button that says 'click here'" or "the button that reads 'click here'"?

Yes, I'd use one of those. Probably the former in speech or informal writing, and the latter in formal writing.

I might use something else if I had a reason to be more technical, at the level appropriate such as "the button with the label 'click here'", the button with the content 'click here'", but only if there was a reason why I cared that e.g. it used a `<button>` with content rather than an `<input>` with a value, or it used text rather than an image.

(I'd also likely say "the button that said 'click here' before I fixed that because it described just one way of using it, and said nothing about what the button did").